Power App with premium connector can be ran by users with non premium license
I have a power app uses two premium connectors:

runs a sql server stored procedure.
Saves a file to azure storage.

Both of these actions are carried out by flows when the user clicks a button.
I dont know how the app runs successfully however.
Users do not have premium licenses & the app does not have a per app plan.
The users have the following Power Platform Licenses:

Power Apps for Office 365, a part of M365 A5 for Student use benefit license
Powerapps per app baseline access

would appreciate any thoughts on why the users can  use premium connectors without a premium license.

In your flows just take all premium connection references to your or someone with premium licence. You can do so in Run as user option in you flow settings

To do so you need atleast one id (usually a service id) which have all required premium licences. Then you need to share all flows/app with that service id and take all premium connection references to that service id name in Run as User setting in each flow. You can follow this article.
Just one thing to take care, if any premium connector is used inside your PowerApp directly then each user will need premium licence. (If only database is a premium one then you can use virtual tables too)
